# Generating N x N grid to display in center of window using OpenGL/C

Tags: c, opengl

I need to create an NxN gameboard that's determined by the user input (ie if they enter 6, it'll be a 6x6 gameboard, etc), and create a tic-tac toe like game. I'm just starting and was trying to build the board, but I can only get it to create a 5 x 5 board in the upper right hand corner and I'd like to make it the full window screen. Here's some of the code so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h> //for text output
    #include <stdlib.h> //for atof() function
    #include <GL/glut.h> //GL Utility Toolkit


    //to hold for size and tokens for gameboard
    float grid, tokens; 
    void init(void);

    /*Function to build the board*/
    void buildGrid(float size) {
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        glVertex2f(0.0, i/5.0f);
        glVertex2f(1.0, i/5.0f);
        glVertex2f(i/5.0f, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(i/5.0f, 1.0);
    }
    glEnd();
    }

    /*Callback function for display */
    void ourDisplay(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    buildGrid(grid);
    glFlush();
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /*User arguments*/
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("You are missing parts of the argument!");
        printf("\n Need game size and how many in a row to win by\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Take arguments and convert to floats*/
    grid = atof(argv[1]);
    tokens = atof(argv[2]);


    /* Settupp OpenGl and Window */
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    /* Set up display  */
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);       // obvious
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);       // obvious
    glutCreateWindow("Tic Tac Oh");     // window title

    /* Call the display callback handler */
    glutDisplayFunc(ourDisplay);

    init();

    /* Start the main loop that waits for events to happen and
       then to process them */
    glutMainLoop();
    }
```

I'm thinking it has to do with the x,y coordinates of glVertex2f, I've tried using different coordinates (negatives) and it would just move the box into a different quarter of the window. I'm also thinking that the coordinates of the window (800 x 800) needs to be manipulated somehow, but I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the old-school fixed-function pipeline, but you're not setting up your model-view-projection matrixes.  This means that your OpenGL window uses "clip space" coordinates, which go from -1 to +1.  So, the lower-left corner of your screen is (-1, -1), and the upper right is (+1, +1).

At the bare minimum, you will probably want to call `glOrtho()` to set your projection matrix, then `glTranslatef()` and `glScalef()` to set up your modelview matrix.  (Or you can just continue to supply coordinates in clip space, but there's no real advantage to doing that, so you might as well choose your own coordinate system to make things easier for you.)

This will be covered in any OpenGL 1.x tutorial, perhaps you just haven't read that far yet.  Look for phrases "matrix stack", "projection matrix", "modelview matrix".